# Traducción de la "that" enfática

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

¿Cómo se traduciría la frase inglesa siguiente?

> One can't know what they are thinking about, only that they are
>   thinking

Pensaba en

> (1) No se puede saber lo que piensan, solo que piensan

Pero me parece que la segunda cláusula carece de ese sentido de énfasis que aporta la inglesa

> One can't know what they are thinking about, only *that* they are thinking

En general, ¿cuál sería la mejor traducción de esta *that* enfática, es decir, no la palabra en sí, sino el sentido? ¿O es la traducción (1) correcta?

Comment: A mi la traducción me parece correcta. Podrías dar más énfasis con algo como "No se puede saber lo que piensan, solo que **efectivamente** piensan", pero podrías haber hecho lo mismo en inglés (por ejemplo "[...] only that they are **indeed** thinking"). Ese `que` me parece la traducción adecuada para el `that`.

Comment: Es un caso interesante de lo importante que son los acentos. La frase _solo que piensan_ quiere decir "only that they are thinking". Sin embargo, _solo qué piensan_ querría decir "only *what* they are thinking".

Comment: Careful, "Saber lo que piensan" is *to know what they think*, that is, to know *what their opinion is*.  *To know what they are thinking about* is "saber en qué están pensando."

Answer (score 2):

La traducción correcta me parece que es

> No se puede saber *qué* piensan, solo *que* piensan

El primer `qué` alude a que desconocemos, lo que están pensando,  mientras que el segundo `que` a que los sabemos pensantes.

Comment: Alguna razón para traducir "piensan" en vez de "están pensando"?

Comment: Ninguna en particular. Me parece que "suena mejor" si consideramos la frase descontextualizada. Igualmente, habría que analizar el contexto al que pertenece la frase para hacer una mejor traducción.

Comment: @roetnig - "estar pensando"  is more about the thinking process, while "pensar"  is more about the opinion being held.

Comment: My question is regarding the verb tense. It doesn't match in the translation and I cannot find a reason.

Comment: @roetnig - please see my answer and check if it addresses your concern.  I hope you'll notify me if you write a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

A mi aviso

> ... solo que piensan

no queda equivalente a tu frase original.

Hay varias maneras de resolver el problema, por ejemplo:

> solo que en algo piensan
>
> solo que sí piensan
>
> solo se puede afirmar la acción de pensar

N.B. La primera parte sería "en qué piensan" o "de qué piensan", porque "saber qué piensan" quiere decir "saber cuál es su opinión."